# How can I execute an mySQL query in another MySQL query with express.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

we have an issue when we want to execute a query that takes the output from another query.

```js
connection.query(`SELECT * from Database.table1`, function (err, rows, fields) {


        for (var item of rows) {
            allcounts += item.count
            number = item.number          
            console.log(allcounts)
            console.log(number)
            
            
            connection.query(`DELETE from Database.table2 where numbers = ${number}`, function (err, rows, fields) {

                console.log("delete successfull")
                

            })
            console.log("Step One finished !")
        }

        
    })
```

The way it should work is, that rows in the first query is returning two JSON objects. Each object stands for a specific product with a count(count) and a product number(number). This products should be deleted in another table in the database.

You can see that we want to loop through the output(rows) of our first statement and execute another  statement with this output(rows). This works but express is executing the code in the wrong direction...

Heres the output:

```js
0.89
12345
Step One finished!
2.28
32598
Step One finished!
delete successfull
delete successfull
```

Its showing us the number and is adding the counts correctly! 
The strange thing is that both queries are executed AFTER both counts are added and the number is shown...

We tried several solutions but no one was the right for us.

It would be great if anyone could help us soon :)

Comment: Those `delete successful` messages only get printed later, because `connection.query` runs asynchronously. The execution does not wait until it is finished and immediately prints `Step One finished !`.

Comment: Thanks but the delete query isn't working as well...

Comment: Try logging the error, the second query might have failed. Otherwise you can console log the raw sql query and run it directly on the database server to see if that works.

Comment: The query is correct, we ran it directly on the server.

Comment: Try logging `err` in the callback of the delete query. You usually should check if this is something else than `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your for-loop doesn't wait for the **[asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Asynchronous)** `connection.query()` to finish before continuing with the next iteration.
You can use [**promises**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to solve that issue.

I've included some commented sample code using promises below
(untested, so you may have to squash a bug) .

Note:

- the second query in the loop doesn't make sense in my opinion.
  It's better to do everything in a single query.
- Search around and read up on [using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).
  You'll be glad you did when you got the basics.

```js
function getNumbers() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query(`SELECT * from Database.table1`,
            function(err, rows, fields) {
                // if an error occured we let the caller know it didn't work out with reject()
                // if everthing went well, we pass on the result data with resolve()
                return (err) ? reject(err) : resolve(rows);
            });
    });
}

getNumbers()
    // below code be executed AFTER the first query succesfully completed
    .then(function(rows) {
        // use Array.prototype.map() with Array.prototype.join()
        // to create string of numbers for deletion query,
        // while also calculating total
        let totalCount = 0;
        const numbersTotal = rows
            .map(item => {
                numbersTotal += item.number;
                return item.number;
            })
            .join();

        console.log("String of numbers: " + numbers);
        console.log("numbersTotal: " + totalCount);

        // now we can achieve the same result
        // using only 2 queries instead of a loop
        numbers.length > 0 && connection.query(
            `DELETE from Database.table2 where numbers in ${numbers}`,
            function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log("delete successfull");
            }
        );
    })
    .catch(err =>
        // stop immediatly when a mysql error occurs
        setImmediate(() => {
            throw err;
        })
    );
```

Comment: I am new in javascript and express.js and I have no experience with promises yet. Is there any chance to get an example regarding to my code?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try with 2 solutions other than promises

1) using anonymous function which blocks the for loop for next iteration untill the query is executed

connection.query(`SELECT * from Database.table1`, function (err, rows, fields) {


        for (var item of rows) {

           (function (item){


           allcounts += item.count
            number = item.number          
            console.log(allcounts)
            console.log(number)


            connection.query(`DELETE from Database.table2 where numbers = ${number}`, function (err, rows, fields) {

                console.log("delete successfull")


            })
            console.log("Step One finished !")
            })(item);


        }


    })


2) using IN in where clause


at takes the output from another query.

connection.query(`SELECT * from Database.table1`, function (err, rows, fields) {


       let numbers = [];

        for (var item of rows) {

            numbers.push(item.number);
            }


            connection.query(`DELETE from Database.table2 where numbers IN ("+numbers+")`, function (err, rows, fields) {
                connection.release();
                console.log("delete successfull")


            })
            console.log("Step One finished !")



    })
```